# Android studio flutter dart, on start white screen blocked my appli, someone know how i can do

Tags: flutter

i got little prob with the white screen on my application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYSF3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAJqS.png)

I install & uninstall, look the variables roads

flutter run OK
main.dart OK
flutter doctor is all green, i don t know why i block if someone can help me.
Thank